# Alfresco keystore failure for ACS 7.4

Tags: tomcat, alfresco

Has anyone managed to get a working keystore for ACS 7+, *for the community zip distribution*?

I've got mTLS with Solr working, but the issue is that the Alfresco log is complaining about its own encryption keystore:

```
org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 08280000 Keystores are invalid
...
Caused by: org.alfresco.encryption.InvalidKeystoreException: The key with alias metadata has been changed, re-instate the previous keystore
```

I'm using the default keystore from `alfresco-content-services-community-distribution-7.4.0.zip`. This is two files:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 foo foo 645 May  3 20:59 keystore
-rw-r--r-- 1 foo foo 359 May  3 20:59 keystore-passwords.properties
```

where 'keystore' is a 'Java JCE KeyStore'. These two files are copied to the server in directory `/opt/tomcat/updated/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/keystore/metadata-keystore/`, and:

```
# shared/classes/alfresco-global.properties
dir.keystore=/opt/tomcat/updated/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/keystore
```

And

```
# bin/catalina.sh
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="\                                                                                                                                                                             
 -Dencryption.keystore.type=JCEKS \                                                                                                                                                                     
 -Dencryption.cipherAlgorithm=DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding \                                                                                                                                                 
 -Dencryption.keyAlgorithm=DESede \                                                                                                                                                                     
 -Dencryption.keystore.location=/opt/tomcat/updated/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/keystore/metadata-keystore/keystore \                                                                             
 -Dmetadata-keystore.password=mp6yc0UD9e \                                                                                                                                                              
 -Dmetadata-keystore.aliases=metadata \                                                                                                                                                                 
 -Dmetadata-keystore.metadata.password=oKIWzVdEdA \                                                                                                                                                     
 -Dmetadata-keystore.metadata.algorithm=DESede"
```

In other words, `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` points to the actual JCE keystore, and `dir.keystore` points to two directories above this keystore. This doesn't work, giving the error above. There are lots of variations on the net of exactly what `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` and `dir.keystore` should point to (ie. the JCE KeyStore, or the metadata directory,  or the keystore directory above the metadata directory), and I think I've tried pretty much all of these. I've also tried:

1. Locating the keystore directory in `alf_data`, but I think this is now obsolete
2. Generating a new keystore with `keytool` (ie. 'Manual keystore generation' from [here](https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/latest/admin/security/#keystore-generation) and [here](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-hub/data-encryption/ba-p/290196))
3. deleting the keystore, and adding a new `KeyData` in `keystore-passwords.properties` using `org.alfresco.encryption.GenerateSecretKey` (ie. 'Automatic keystore generation')

None of these work, producing either "Key metadata is missing from keystore" or "The key with alias metadata has been changed, re-instate the previous keystore". Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is more or less self-explanatory:

```
Caused by: org.alfresco.encryption.InvalidKeystoreException: The key with alias metadata has been changed, re-instate the previous keystore
```

You use or generated a new metadata encryption key but you should not do that for an existing repository, except you know what you're doing and why. In that case you need to configure the previous key as `encryption.keystore.backup.location`, otherwise alfresco is not able to decrypt encrypted properties. Unfotunately Alfresco encrypts an property to store the Alfresco edition and if the metadata key is no longer available you will not be able to start the repository again.

hopefully you still have the old metadata key somewhere, so you can configure the old one as a fall back.

e.g.:

```
# backup location is used for migration - if decrypting from encryption.keystore doesn't work
# alfresco tries encryption.keystore.backup which is normally empty
encryption.keystore.backup.location=${dir.keystore}/../backup-keystore/metadata.keystore
encryption.keystore.backup.provider=
encryption.keystore.backup.type=JCEKS
encryption.keystore.backup.keyMetaData.location=${dir.keystore}/../backup-keystore/metadata-keystore-passwords.properties
```

Alfresco will fall back the the key found in the backup.location if it fails to decrypt with the current configured metadata key.

Alfresco had to generate new keystores since DES/3DES keys are no longer supported for SSL but this doesn't necessarily mean you have to replace the metadata key.

Please Check [Mutual TLS](https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/latest/config/mtls/) in Alfresco's documentation

In future you may prefer [Shared Secret Communication Mode for Repository and SOLR](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-blog/shared-secret-communication-mode-for-repository-and-solr/ba-p/309862) instead of Mutual TLS to secure communication between Alfresco Repository and Solr but as said before, metadata key has nothing to do with the keystores to secure communication with Solr.

Comment: Hi Heiko - I didn't actually create a new key until I got desperate (step 2 under 'I've also tried' above). Everything I tried *before* that used the default keystore in the zip distribution, so the key never changed, and the error message makes no sense. Also note that mutual TLS between ACS and Solr does work - the issue is that ACS is complaining about its own encryption, not mTLS or the conenction to Solr.

Comment: Do you happen to know *what* exactly was encrypted? I could just delete it and re-install it from source. There's nothing in the repo, and clearing out `alf_data` doesn't get rid of the error message.

Comment: Hi @EML, is this a new repo or are you trying to migrate an existing repo? If you clear alf_data/contentstore you would also need to drop/recreate the alfresco database. The encrypted property is stored in the db.

Comment: I guess you just have to configure the metadata keystore from your previous install in the backup.location to make Alfresco happy

Comment: Thanks - clearing `alf_data` *and* flushing the DB fixes this; if you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it. I'm trying to automate the installation procedure for a new repo, but the procedure is not yet correct, so I sometimes get this problem.

Comment: well - the above answer is related to the error message you posted. How to clean/empty the repository is another story and does not relate directly to your question. So I will leave the answer as it is.
If a db does not fit to the data in `alf_data/contentstore` you should see an exception complaining about the wrong `dir.root`. If you cleanup the repo you should also remove the solr index.